# Continue sql statement after an error in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a view which this is its sql

```
    -- DROP VIEW bd_segment_id;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bd_segment_id AS 
 SELECT final.gid,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY final.gid) AS row_number,
    degrees(st_azimuth(ff.sp, ff.ep) - 1.57079633::double precision) AS az_deg,
    st_length(ff.st_makeline) AS st_length,
    ff.st_makeline
   FROM bd_segment_geom ff
     JOIN final ON st_touches(ff.st_makeline, final.geom)
  GROUP BY final.gid, ff.sp, ff.ep, ff.st_makeline;

ALTER TABLE bd_segment_id
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

while running each query of this table I have faced this error

```
    ERROR:  GEOSTouches: TopologyException: side location conflict at 553655.77720000315 3474241.5185000021
********** Error **********

ERROR: GEOSTouches: TopologyException: side location conflict at 553655.77720000315 3474241.5185000021
SQL state: XX000
```

Is there any way for sql to pass errors and continues to do the rest of sql?I know the problem is an internal error but I want sql jump of it..
I have searched and found [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) in section 39.6.6. Trapping Errors is says how we can use an EXCEPTION clause but I don't know how to write  handler_statements that says sql to continue.
I need sth like `try catch` in C# or jave
can some one please help me with this problem?

thank you

Comment: What client are you using? psql? pgadmin? something else?

Comment: @Bill I use pgadmin ,Does it matters on the way we must write sql?

Comment: pgadmin can run straight sql, which as far as I know does not provide this functionality. It can also run pgscript http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgscript.html which provides you options for this.

Comment: @Bill could you please tell me how to rewrite sql statement to provide and error exeption?

Comment: It's not that simple.